# TeX Live 2011: tlmgr not using xz after system upgrade

Tags: errors, texlive, linux, texmf, updating

I have moved my TeX Live installation directories from one computer to another when I bought a newer system. I simply did a `tar cfj texlive.tbz /texlive/` (the root directory where I had put TeX Live) and later unpacked it using `tar xjf texlive.tbz`.

Almost everything works fine, including software updates using `tlmgr`, both in the command line and using the GUI. The only problem is that `tlmgr` is not handling backups properly. This is the tail of a `tlmgr update --all` command:

```
[14/16, 01:56/01:56] update: collection-bibtexextra [1k] (24610 -> 25686) ... done
Can't exec "/tmp/fecOgscNe7/xz.x86_64-linux": Permissão negada at /opt/texlive/2011/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 636.
/usr/local/bin/tlmgr: Couldn't find /opt/texlive/2011/tlpkg/backups/collection-fontutils.r24759.tar.xz
[15/16, 01:57/01:57] update: collection-fontutils [1k] (24759 -> 25704) ... done
Can't exec "/tmp/fecOgscNe7/xz.x86_64-linux": Permissão negada at /opt/texlive/2011/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 636.
/usr/local/bin/tlmgr: Couldn't find /opt/texlive/2011/tlpkg/backups/collection-latexextra.r25679.tar.xz
[16/16, 01:57/01:57] update: collection-latexextra [4k] (25679 -> 25713) ... done
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running updmap-sys ...
done running updmap-sys.
Completed.
```

When I do an `ls` in the `/opt/texlive/2011/tlpkg/backups` directory querying for the filenames not found I see this

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3888 Mar  1 20:33 /opt/texlive/2011/tlpkg/backups/collection-latexextra.r25489.tar.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20480 Mar  6 21:54 /opt/texlive/2011/tlpkg/backups/collection-latexextra.r25534.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20480 Mar  9 23:35 /opt/texlive/2011/tlpkg/backups/collection-latexextra.r25552.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20480 Mar 16 22:24 /opt/texlive/2011/tlpkg/backups/collection-latexextra.r25574.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20480 Mar 19 20:47 /opt/texlive/2011/tlpkg/backups/collection-latexextra.r25620.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20480 Mar 25 21:28 /opt/texlive/2011/tlpkg/backups/collection-latexextra.r25679.tar
```

The older versions, which are compressed, were manually compressed by me, in the hope that tlmgr would see them in the next update. But it does not happen.

TeX Live is creating the backups uncompressed (`.tar` only) and cannot uncompress them if I compress them manually.

It seems that `tlmgr` is not detecting properly the `xz` program.

What is wrong? How to solve this so that `tlmgr` does not spit these errors any more?

Comment: Maybe your new system has the `/tmp` partition mounted with `noexec`, which would explain the errors in `tlmgr` ouptut.

Comment: My /tmp had the noexec flag. That was it! By the way, I had followed a famous Debian tip and my /tmp is mounted on RAM. I will reboot without noexec and see if it works.